# How to split a geotiff into a standard tiling scheme with Geotools in Java

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, tiling, tiling-scheme

I would like to tile random geotiffs to a standard grid, with a standard size of 256X256 using Geotools in java. My use case is as follows: I receive a "stream" of raster data in the form of multiband geotiffs, most files are over a GB in size. I am then storing them in Hadoop HBase for both spectral analytics and retrieval. I need to break them into smaller pieces, but not arbitrarily; they need to be split on a standard geographic grid so when new images come in and overlap, the tiles line up across all images that overlap over time. I have googled and binged all I can, and can't figure out how to create tiles with Geotools at all.
All of my code for reading the tif, reprojecting etc, all work fine.
Someone please point me in the right direction.

I am using Geotools 11.1, java 7, on windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that GeoTools can manage this out of the box. But the code shouldn't be too hard to knock up to handle your use case.

[The Image Tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html) will get you started with reading in and writing out geotiffs. There is certainly tiling code available in the new [GeoPackage module](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/geopkg) that might already do what you need.

You might also find [JAITools](http://jaitools.org/) (a sister project) useful in the manipulation of your images.

Comment: There is also MBTiles module for GeoServer http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/community/mbtiles/index.html.